# error in spring xml config relating to bean profiles

Tags: spring

I have just recently begun to see some strange errors in my spring sts relating to my spring mvc web application. For the following xml I get an error but can't figure out why because this has always worked for me in the past. Is there something I am doing wrong?

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- import XML fragments to use in the application context  -->

<import resource="spring-resources.xml" />
<import resource="spring-managers.xml" />
<import resource="spring-controllers.xml" />
<import resource="spring-security-common.xml" />
<import resource="spring-interceptors.xml" />
<import resource="spring-cache.xml" />
<import resource="spring-batch.xml" />  
<import resource="spring-data-source.xml" />


<beans profile="mock">
    <import resource="spring-database-mock.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-security-mock.xml" />
</beans>

<beans profile="pre,prod">      
    <import resource="spring-database.xml" />
    <import resource="spring-security.xml" />               
</beans>
```

The error I get is...

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a more recent Spring version in your classpath, at least 3.2.0. `beans profile` appears in `spring-beans-3.2.xsd` for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The beans element around the imports are not nessesary. Tray to remove them.

Comment: thanks for that. I've changed my original post to reflect that. What can I do about the profiles? The error is "Attribute profile is not allowed in element beans"

Comment: @Richie Which Spring Version do you use?

Comment: I am using 3.1.0.RELEASE. I thought it was good practice not to specify version on your xsd and that spring would pick up the latest version available on the classpath. But something has gone wrong here. I've changed the xsd to spring-beans-3.1.xsd and it worked. My errors were gone