# import bean resources based on spring profiles

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Below is the code for servlet-context.xml in my spring project. I want to import demo.xml file in case the profile is prod and demo-test.xml if the profile is test.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <beans profile="test">
        <import resource="demo-test.xml"></import>
    </beans>
    <beans profile="prod">
        <import resource="demo.xml"></import>
    </beans>


    <task:annotation-driven
            executor="defaultExecutor"/>
    <!-- add an exception handler here. -->

    <task:executor id="defaultExecutor"
                   pool-size="50-200"
                   queue-capacity="1200"
                   keep-alive="10"
                   rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>

</beans:beans>
```

But I am getting error `The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'beans'.` for line `<beans profile="test">` and `'resource' attribute should be defined` for `<import resource="demo-test.xml"></import>`

Based on [error in spring xml config relating to bean profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23830630/error-in-spring-xml-config-relating-to-bean-profiles) I even tried changing context to "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd" but no luck. Can some one help me understand what does this error mean and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` at the top of your xml file uses `mvc` instead of `beans`, meaning that the default namespace is `mvc` instead of `beans`. Either, qualify the bean tag: use `<beans:beans profile="test">...` instead of `<beans profile="test">...` and `<beans:import resource...` instead of `<import resource...`, OR change the default namespace to `beans` to use the xml as is

Comment: no I have already imported this servlet-context.xml in my Application.java file in `@ImportResources`

Comment: moreover the error is something else, you may check that at the end of the question.

Comment: See correct answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26836345/cvc-complex-type-2-4-c-the-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can. The `<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` at the top of your xml file uses `mvc` instead of `beans`, otherwise, qualify the bean tag: use `<beans:beans profile="test">...` instead of `<beans profile="test">...` . Try changing that and test again